# Creating huge excel/pdf file in struts 2 throwing error

Tags: file, java-8, struts2, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

In struts 2 project, I am trying to export pdf and excel. For data like 15000 its working fine but if data exceeds 50000 it is throwing exception.

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not find a java.io.InputStream with the name [inputStream] in the invocation stack. Check the <param name="inputName"> tag specified for this action
```

Struts.xml configuration.

```
<result name="success" type="stream">
    <param name="contentType">application/vnd.ms-excel</param>
    <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
    <param name="contentDisposition">attachment;filename="ActivitiesList.xls"</param>
    <param name="bufferSize">4096</param>
</result>
```

Service.java

```
            public HSSFWorkbook exportInExcel(ActivitiesReportDTO activitiesReportDTO) throws Exception {
    CreateExcelHelper cEH = new CreateExcelHelper("Activities List");

            HSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Activities List");

            HSSFCellStyle cellStyleHeader = cEH.getColHeaderStyle(workbook);
            HSSFCellStyle cellStyleCol = cEH.getColStyle(workbook);

            int headerRowCounter = 0;
            HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(2);
            cEH.getExcelCellStr(row,0,cellStyleHeader,"Sr No");                     
            int i = 0;
            for(EmployeeActivityLogDTO dto : listOfActivities){        
                row = sheet.createRow((short)++rowIndex);

                int dataRowCounter = 0;
                cEH.getExcelCellNum(row,0,cellStyleCol,++i);
                cEH.getExcelCellStr(row,++dataRowCounter,cellStyleCol,dto.getNtLogin());                
            }
            return workbook;
    }
```

Action.java (This is the method in strutsaction.java)

```
public String exportInExcel() {
        try {           
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = activitiesReportService.exportInExcel(activitiesReportDTO);
            ByteArrayOutputStream boas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            workbook.write(boas);
            setInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(boas.toByteArray()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception Occured :", e);
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

Comment: Let me know here if more info required.

Comment: Is there an exposed `inputStream`?

Comment: yes @Dave Newton